# How to align the table data to "centered" and format specific column to % values

Tags: google-apps-script, format, number-formatting, text-alignment

I am trying to create a daily email that sends daily report in a table format. Unfortunately, I am facing 2 problems with the code:

1. The table data is not aligned to center. Instead all the data are on the right side of the table.
2. Column SLA % should be in % format.

Attached is the look of the current email notification.

Below is the code I am using. Really appreciate anyone's advise

```
function getData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = sheet.getSheetByName('Summary');
  var datavalues = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();

  var html= "Dear All," + "\n\n" + "Please find the daily report as below. <br><br>" + '<table>';

  if(datavalues.length>0){

  for(var i=0; i<datavalues.length;i++){
  
  html+= '<tr style = bgcolor = "Black">';
  for(var j=0; j<datavalues[i].length;j++)
  {
    if(i==0)
    {
      html+= Utilities.formatString('<td bgcolor = "Orange";style = "border:2px solid black"<th>%s</th></td>' ,datavalues[i][j]);
    }
    else{
      html+= Utilities.formatString('<td style = "border:2px solid black" > %s</td>',datavalues[i][j]);

    }
  }
  }

  html+= '<table>';

}

return html;

}

function sendEmail(){
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to:"xxxxx.xxxx@xxxxxx.com",
    subject: "Daily Report",
    htmlBody: getData()
  })


}
```

1. Table data to be in "centered" alignment
2. Column SLA % to be in % format

Answer (score 0):

### Suggestion

You would have to add a `text-align:center` HTML tag to center the table data. A simple `if` statement can then be used to display the values under the column `SLA %` to % format.

You can try modifying your existing `for` loop with this:

```
   for (var i = 0; i < datavalues.length; i++) {
      html += '<tr style = bgcolor = "Black">';
      for (var j = 0; j < datavalues[i].length; j++) {
        if (i == 0) {
          html+= Utilities.formatString('<td bgcolor = "Orange";style = "border:2px solid black"<th>%s</th></td>' ,datavalues[i][j]);
        }
        else {
          if (datavalues[0][j] == 'SLA %') datavalues[i][j] = (datavalues[i][j] *100).toFixed(2) + ' %'; //converts all entries under the SLA % column to % values then adds a % sign.
          html += Utilities.formatString('<td style = "border:2px solid black;text-align:center" > %s</td>', datavalues[i][j]);
        }
      }
    }
```

### Sample data in Google Sheets

[image: Google Sheets sample data]

### Email Output

[image: expected result when email is received]

Note that the code above only centers the table data. If you wish to center the table headers as well, you can replace

```
html += Utilities.formatString('<td bgcolor = "Orange";style = "border:2px solid black;text-align:center"<th>%s</th></td>', datavalues[i][j]);
```

with

```
html += Utilities.formatString('<th bgcolor = "Orange";style = "border:2px solid black">%s</th>', datavalues[i][j]);
```

Contents of the `<th> </th>` tags are centered by default.

### Reference

[HTML Horizontal alignment](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table_align.asp)

Comment: Thank you so much! The code works perfectly now. Amazing!

Comment: Happy to help! If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvoting the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)